# Salesforce Callouts using Named Credentials

Tags: salesforce

In Salesforce, Making a POST callout using apex and generating the bearer token.
Using the bearer token, making a GET callout and then parsing the JSON response.

However when I am trying to replicate the same procedure using Named Credential I fail to achieve the requirement.(O AUth 2.0)

```java
HTTPRequest feedRequest = new HTTPRequest();
feedRequest.setEndpoint('callout:Salesforce_NC/the Get Callout Enpoint');
feedRequest.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
feedRequest.setMethod('GET');
HTTP http = new HTTP();
HTTPResponse feedResponse = http.send(feedRequest);
System.debug(feedResponse.getBody() + feedResponse.getStatusCode());
```

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, you can [edit] your question and format it properly there. Why is this question tagged "javascript" and "reactjs"? This code looks like java

Comment: It's Salesforce Apex. @sidd47, it's unlikely anyone can help you unless you explain what error you receive and give more detail about what you're trying to do. Since Named Credentials manage authentication for you, it's not clear why you're trying to use one to get an OAuth token.

Comment: This should be moved to [Salesforce SE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com)